# services.xml build.xml cannot generate the stubs

Tags: java, xml, ant, apache-axis, stub

build xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project name="3500259" basedir="." default="generate.stubs">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <path id="axis2.classpath">
        <!-- pick up log4j.properties in the project root -->
        <pathelement location="./src"/>
        <fileset dir="F:\axisServiceHome\axis2-1.6.2/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <target name="generate.stubs">
        <!-- modified and commented by 3500259 -->
        <java classname="org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java"   classpathref="axis2.classpath">
            <!-- the location of the wsdl (which is automatically generated 
            by Axis) -->
            <arg line="-uri ${librarywsdl.uri}"/>
            <!-- overwrite existing generated code (if it exists) -->
            <arg line="-or"/>
            <!-- Generate Java stub (since axis is multi-language) -->
            <arg line="-l java"/>
            <!-- unwrap paramaters to java types -->
            <arg line="-uw"/>
            <!-- specifiy destination package -->
            <arg line="-p stubs"/>
            <!-- databinding technique between SOAP and Java (ADB=proprietry 
            Axis data binding) -->
            <arg line="-d adb"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

build properties file

```
librarywsdl.uri=http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Library?wsdl
axis2.home=F:/axisServiceHome/axis2-1.6.2
```

services xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
 <servicegroup>
<service name="AccommodationServiceImpl"class="accommodation.AccommodationServiceImpl"scope="application" targetNamespace="http://AccommodationServiceImpl/">
    <description>AccommodationService</description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
            class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"  />
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
            class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
    </messageReceivers>
    <schema schemaNamespace="http://AccommodationServiceImpl/xsd" />
    <parameter    name="AccommodationServiceImpl">AccommodationServiceImpl</parameter>
</service>
<service name="AirlineServiceImpl" class="airline.AirlineServiceImpl"  scope="application" targetNamespace="http://AirlineServiceImpl/">
    <description>AirlineService</description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
            class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
            class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
    </messageReceivers>
    <schema schemaNamespace="http://AirlineServiceImpl/xsd" />
    <parameter name="AirlineServiceImpl">AirlineServiceImpl</parameter>
</service>
</servicegroup>
```

error are throw out

```
Retrieving document at '${librarywsdl.uri}'.
 [java] org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
```

Is there anything wrong with the three files? I cannot generate the `.arr` file. These three files are from a web service project I am working on.

Comment: Is your wsdl uri correct and is your web/app server up and running?

Comment: where can I find my uri? my server is up and running

Comment: its defined by you via  property `librarywsdl.uri`?

Comment: but the "librarywsdl.uri=http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Library?wsdl" is what I copied from another project, am not sure what is the correct uri in this case? any idea how i can find it out?

Comment: The comment in build.xml said  <!-- the location of the wsdl (which is automatically generated 
            by Axis) -->

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, I need to create service to get .arr then use this .arr to get WSDL for building stubs. I create a service build and generated a .arr file, but after I uploaded it to the server, it throw an error which makes me cannot get WSDL.
Error as below:
Error: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: Invalid services.xml found at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:150) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:73) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:94) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.Scheduler$SchedulerTimerTask.run(Scheduler.java:93) at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source) at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid services.xml found at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:111) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:143) ... 12 more